# Displaying cross sections/3D volumes in QGIS 3.X

Tags: qgis-3, 3d, geology

Is there is a way to display vertical images (cross sections) in a 3D view window in QGIS 3? I want to display some cross sections underneath a geological map overlain on the topography.

I can do this in ArcMap & ArcScene, but would like to know if its possible in QGIS. My input data would be a series of images (the vertical profiles) hanging off 3D polylines which are their surface profiles.

Something like this:

[image]

Image courtesy of the [USGS](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0312/modeling-the-terrain-below.html)

Comment: qgis2threejs might be able to do this if it can extrude lines. Not sure if it would support being able to project one of your profiles as a texture onto each extruded line (although that might be doable by hacking the generated javascript).

Comment: cool - I'll give that a go this evening. thanks for the reply