# Displaying raster images vertically in QGIS 3.x (Geological cross section)

Tags: qgis, geology, cross-section

I'm aware this has been asked before to an extent, but the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295586/displaying-cross-sections-3d-volumes-in-qgis-3-x) doesn't really cover raster images.

I want to 'hang' a raster image in 3D alongside a surface. The raster is a geological cross section, and the surface is topography. You can do [this](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=133a6dc35a5f45d094b73effa68fefcb) in ArcScene rather hackily, I was wondering if there is the possibility of doing something similar in QGIS.

Just to be clear the cross sections are hand drawn and there is no actual data to sample or interpolate in 3D to make a section. I'm not slicing a 3D model, as the area around the cross section is almost 100% uncertain.

If you can extrude between shapefiles/vectors I could digitise the cross section lines and extrude them but I've no idea how to do this in QGIS and produce something that looks publication ready and better than simply displaying the sections in 3D space.

How can I do this?

Comment: In 2D you can use a raster image as "fill" inside a polygon. If this option exists in 3D mode, you could use the raster to fill a vertical, rectangular polygon with the same dimensions as the raster image.

Comment: csk - I'll give this a go this afternoon and report back! Thanks